# How to enable Database Auditing on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, security, select

I want to audit SQL database activities, but when I am trying to enable Database Level Adut specification, it is capturing all activities that is done from application side and also from queries that are done on the database.

I don't want to capture activities that are done from application side on that database. I want only to capture activities from Database side. Like SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE activities that are done on SQL server Database.

Comment: What do you mean by "application side"? Could you give some example?

Comment: "*I don't want to capture activities that are done from application side on that database. I want only to capture activities from Database side.*" - Every query executed on a SQL Server stems from a connection made by an application / process. I'm assuming you're more so looking for the ad-hoc queries people are running from SQL Server Management Studio / SSMS (which is an application)?

Comment: There's a few ways you could do this, but the first to come to mind are DDL triggers and Extended Events.  A DDL trigger will probably also catch "application side" changes as well, but you could possibly configure an Extended Event to ignore that.

Comment: In database specification you could filter on Login, if your adhoc and application connections have specific logins you could filter.